# How to use the mysql & sqlserver database functions in single php file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

My application is developed by php and mysql. Then I also use the sql server.

Now the application displays the blank page while i retrieve the records from sql server

database based on one search criteria value(This value in mysql database).

Please help what is the problem in my application

In this file mysql data also displayed. the configuration.php contains sqlserver connection

**my php file (UI file)**

```
include("configuration.php");

  $select_dob="select DISTINCT  `FirstName` , `LastName`,`Address1`,`City`,`State`,`Zip`,`DOB` from `tblCustomer` where `DOB`='$dob' order by `FirstName` asc";

 $query_dob=mssql_query($select_dob) or die ("Error".mssql_error()); 
  $query_row=mssql_num_rows($query_dob);
```

Comment: Any code example would be nice to the answers could be more specific.

Comment: Just use mssql_X and mysql_x functions on the same file, there is not problem with that.

Comment: 'the application displays the blank page' - well you're not outputting anything in the code sample you've given. Have you got error reporting on? Is there anything in the (Apache?) error log?

Answer (score 0):

> How to use the mysql & sqlserver database functions in single php file?

Usual way you're working with them alone. There are no special issues in using them in one script.

> Now the application displays the blank page

So, your problem that you're unable to see error messages. Turn all error reporting on and also use database-driver specific error handling functions like mysql_error() one.

> Please help what is the problem in my application

Nobody can tell you that from your problem description consists of "blank page" only. Don't you understand that?